# Display List of Books filtered by dropdownlist php

Tags: php, mysql, web

Well i guess this must be a really dump question, but it's just that i 've been trying but with no results.
I have a webpage in which a display a list of books from my database, which works just fine. But now i'd like to add a dropdownlist so the customer will be able to filter books by category. 
How can i acchieve this?. 
I have this image so it may help you. Thanks in advance for your answwers!
[image: mi image]

```
<?php 
require_once("../../seguridad/secure_user.php");
include("conexion.php");

$query = mysql_query("select * from libro order by id_libro desc");
?>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead bgcolor="3286CE">
           <th><font color="#ffffff">Titulo
           <th><font color="#ffffff">Categoria
           <th><font color="#ffffff">Descripcion
           <th>
      </thead>
      <?php
       while ($datos = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
              ?>
              <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $datos[3]?>
                  <td><?php echo $datos[5]?>
                  <td><?php echo $datos[2]?>
                  <td><?php echo $datos[4]?>
              <?php
       }
       ?>
   </table>
 </div>
```

```
 ?>
```

Comment: Even though your browser may not care, it's good practice to close your <tr>, <td> and <th> tags.

Answer (score 0):

1) upgrade your code mysql is depreciated and you should be using PDO or mysqli

2) Your query would need to be modified to allow the category to be changed in the WHERE clause.

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from libro order by id_libro desc WHERE category = $category");
```

You would restructure your code to allow these changes to take place, without knowing your table names we cannot restructure this for you.